# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the typescript error in angular application while trying to set types for a data inside `reduce` method.

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ICar'. 
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ICar'.
```

Back-end side sends me following array of objects which I pass to `getCarProperty` function:

```
[
    {
        created: null
        id: "124545484822"
        details: {
            name: "Ford focus"
            number: "128888"
        }
        status: "working"
        usedFrom: null
        usedUntil: null
    },
    {
        created: null
        id: "99525484827"
        details: {
            name: "Honda Accord"
            number: "598402"
        }
        status: "working"
        usedFrom: null
        usedUntil: null
    }
]
```

Here is how function looks like:

```
getCarProperty = (obj: ICar, path: string): any => {
    if (path.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      return path.split('.').reduce((o: ICar, p: string) => {
        return o && o[p]; <----- HERE IS THE ISSUE
      }, obj);
    }

    return Array.from(path).reduce((o: ICar, p: string) => {
      return o && o[p]; <------ Here is the issue
    }, obj);
};
```

When `details.name` property passes via `path` argument then I am able to get the value of the `name` property (such as 'Ford focus' and 'Honda Accord').

Here are interfaces that used for this data:

```
export interface IDetail {
   name: string;
   number: string;
}

export interface IContract {
     created: string;
     id: string;
     detail: IDetail;
     status: string;
     usedFrom: string;
     usedUntil: string;
}
```

I tried to apply different solutions such as [propName as **keyof**  ICar] or set generic types, but none of them were successful. So, what is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did the answers to other question with the exact same title as yours tell you?

Comment: they use [propName as keyof ICar] or set generic types but this did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your reduce callback is expecting an object that comply with the `ICar` interface which is true only in the first iteration, on the next iteration of the reduce callback, you won't receive anymore an object of `ICar` type (only `IDetails` or `string`), so the constraint fails. Basically, the return of every iteration return a different type and that's why you cannot use a specific type there, you could use a union of types in some cases though.

To fix your issue, just replace the `ICar` type to `any`, like below. I don't see any issue with this because you are still type checking the `getCarProperty` function parameters.

```js
getCarProperty = (obj: ICar, path: string): any => {
    if (path.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      return path.split('.').reduce((o: any, p: string) => {
        return o && o[p];
      }, obj);
    }

    return Array.of(path).reduce((o: any, p: string) => {
      return o && o[p];
    }, obj);
};
```

If you really want to preserve the types, and you don't want to use `any`, you could try the function below, but I don't see much advantage since you are already typing your function parameters.

```js
function getCarProperty(obj: ICar, path: string): any {
  type CarOrDetailType = ICar | IDetail; // <-- All the possibilities for the reduce `previousValue` callback parameter. If the ICar interface changes, you might need to adjust this.
  type CarOrDetailKey = keyof CarOrDetailType;

  if (path.indexOf('.') > -1) {
    const typedPath = path.split('.') as Array<CarOrDetailKey>;
    return typedPath.reduce((o: CarOrDetailType, p: CarOrDetailKey): any => {
      return o && o[p];
    }, obj);
  }

  const typedPath = Array.of(path) as Array<CarOrDetailKey>;
  return typedPath.reduce((o: CarOrDetailType, p: CarOrDetailKey) => {
    return o && o[p];
  }, obj);
}
```

Two more issues that I found with your code, but it could have been that you miscopied, are:

- Your mock data don't have comas after every property, so it has not a valid syntax.
- You used `Array.from(path)` on a string, but you probably wanted `Array.of(path)`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, it works! but I would like to get a solution that will allow to avoid the usage of `any`.

Comment: I understand your desire to keep `any` types at bay, but in this case I really think it was OK. Nonetheless, I gave another functional example without the `any` type, but then again, I don't see any gain.